# Extract set of characters between "-" using regex powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

Hello how can i extract the date 10/3/2015 6:22:51 PM from the below expression using regex.

```
 disable - Olis - 10/3/2015 6:22:51 PM - est 10 -
 CN=K,CN=Users,DC=v,DC=com
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'disable - Olis - 10/3/2015 6:22:51 PM - est 10 -' -match '- (\d.*?) -'`

**EDIT:**

You can use the `$matches` command to display all results - here is a really simple example:

```
$str = "disable - Olis - 10/3/2015 6:22:51 PM - est 10 - CN=K,CN=Users,DC=v,DC=com" 

# PATTERN:
$str -match "- (\d.*?) -"
True

# Reading data matching the pattern from string:
$matches 
Name                           Value
----                           -----
0                              10/3/2015 6:22:51 PM
$matches[0] 
10/3/2015 6:22:51 PM
```

Comment: You might indicate how you use $matches to find the extracted characters.

Comment: @MikeShepard just included your suggestion